# how can i delete the short lines of the colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, colorbar, short

I've plotting with matplotlib and I have short lines in colorbar :

[image]

How can I delete the short lines to have a colorbar like this picture:

[image]

What I need to change in my code?
My code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from matplotlib import rc
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib as cm

phi = open("file1.txt").read().splitlines()
psi = open("file2.txt").read().splitlines()

# normal distribution center at x=0 and y=5
x = np.array(phi).astype(np.float)
y = np.array(psi).astype(np.float)

plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=400, cmap='bone', norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Distribution')
plt.xlabel(r' Phi ($\phi$)', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel(r'Psi ($\psi$)', fontsize=15)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=11)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=11)
plt.xlim((-180,180))
plt.ylim((-180,180))
plt.axhline(0, color='black')
plt.axvline(0, color='black')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean you want to remove the minor ticks from the colorbar.

You can do this by setting the location of the ticks using a [`LogLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator) from the [`matplotlib.ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module. By default, this does not have any minor ticks (i.e. no ticks between the integer powers of the base), so we can use the `LogLocator` with no other options required.

You just need to keep a reference to the `colorbar` as you make it (here I call it `cb`), then you can use the [`set_ticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase.set_ticks) method on that. Make sure you also set `update_ticks=True` to make this update the ticks before making the plot.

(I used some fake data, but otherwise didn't change anything else in your script):

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

...

cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_ticks(ticker.LogLocator(), update_ticks=True)

...
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To completely remove the ticks ("How can I delete the short lines?") you can use `tick_params` on the axes of the colorbar.

```
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.tick_params(size=0)
```

[image]